# AngularJS redirect to view on button click

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load a new view when a button is clicked.  For some reason it isn't working with one of my paths.  It will work with the path /lookup and will go to the lookup page, but when I change the path to /search it does nothing?  I'm confused.

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {   
    'use strict'
    angular
        .module('crm.ma')
        .controller('navbarCtrl', function ($location) {

           var vm = this;

           vm.redirect = function () {
               $location.url('/search');
           }
       });
})();
```

Here is my button

```
<button class="btn default-btn advancedbtn" ng-click="redirect()">Advanced</button>
```

And here's part of my route file if that will help at all.

```
.state('index.topnavbar', {
            url: '/topnav',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/common/topnavbar.html',
            controller: 'navbarCtrl as vm'

        })
.state('index.search', {
            url: '/search',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/common/topnav_advancedmodal.html',
            controller: 'AdvancedSearchCtrl as vm',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Advanced Search'
            }

        })
```

If any other code is needed please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: the code seems to be fine. Can you post the code on jsFiddle?

Comment: @Dvir  here is a jsFiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/50ap6g7f/  I'm not sure it will be of any use since I can't post all of my code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get any errors in the console? Does your template exist? If Angular can't find your template it won't transition to the route. You can check the network requests and console for errors.

You could try using `ui-sref`:

```
<a ui-sref="index.search">Advanced</a>
```

If you prefer to keep the redirect method, can you add a `console.log` and do you see that log? If not then your scoping is off.

If so, and you prefer to keep your `redirect` method rather than use `ui-sref` (in case you want to check something before redirecting), you can inject `$state` into your controller and call the method:

```
$state.go('index.search');
```

#### Update to add to follow-up question

To help with your follow-up question of reloading if clicking once you're already there, according to the [UI-Router documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref), you can specify the option to reload like this:

```
<a ui-sref="index.search" ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }">Advanced</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  ui-sref works, but I get the problem that once I'm on the search page, if I click the Advanced button a second time it doesn't reload the page.  Is there a way to get it to load everytime the button is clicked>

Comment: Tina you are amazing!  It works perfectly!  Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your call for redirect method are not in the scope. You have to change the `redirect()` to `vm.redirect()` in the html.

before:

```
<button class="btn default-btn advancedbtn" ng-click="redirect()">Advanced</button>
```

after:

```
<button class="btn default-btn advancedbtn" ng-click="vm.redirect()">Advanced</button>
```

Comment: It still does not work even after I add the vm.  It will work for other pages, it just won't redirect to my search page.  I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: When I debug it in firebug I'm getting this error Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you
When you alias controller with some name you need to use aliasName in your view
change you code

```
  <button class="btn default-btn advancedbtn" ng-click="vm.redirect()">Advanced</button>
```

Refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController